# How to remove a layer with ipyleaflet

Tags: python, maps, layer, ipyleaflet

Hya all,
I am plotting aircraft positions contained in a DataFrame df, on a leaflet map using Python.
An icon is created with an airplane symbol.
So I add all markers to the map, using:

```
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        ac = Marker(name = df['callsign'][i],
                    location=(df['latitude'][i], df['longitude'][i]), 
                    icon            = icon, 
                    rotation_angle  = float(df['heading'][i]), 
                    rotation_origin = 'center')
        m.add_layer(ac)
```

For the next update cycle I need to remove these layers (could be up to a hundred) but I cannot find a way to address specifically the layers that need to be removed, although they are defined with the 'name' field:

```
    # remove all the ac symbols before we go into the next loop
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        m.remove_layer(i)
```

Gives this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18204/2482639859.py in <module>
     71     # remove all the ac symbols before we go into the next loop
     72     for i in range(0, len(df)):
---> 73         m.remove_layer(i)
     74         #print(ac.name)
     75 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipyleaflet\leaflet.py in remove_layer(self, rm_layer)
   2152             The layer to remove.
   2153         """
-> 2154         if rm_layer.model_id not in self._layer_ids:
   2155             raise LayerException('layer not on map: %r' % rm_layer)
   2156         self.layers = tuple([layer for layer in self.layers if layer.model_id != rm_layer.model_id])

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'model_id'
```

So it looks like I can reference to these layers somehow, but cannot find how.
Any clues much appreciated.

Comment: Haha, I found out that you can access the map itself and query the layers, with 'm.layers'. This will surely help.

Answer (score 4):

So the answer looks like as follows:

```
    # remove all the ac symbols before we go into the next loop
    # except the first layer because that is the background map
    
    print('There are', len(m.layers), 'layers')
    for i in range(1, len(m.layers)):
        print('Removing layer',i, m.layers[1].name)
        m.remove_layer(m.layers[1])
```

Layer 1 is the map. Because I remove always layer 2 (indexed as 1), the total number of layers goes minus one. So the next cycle I need AGAIN to remove layer 2 (indexed as 1). Hope this makes sense.

However, this removing of layers is very slow... and very visible on the map. It is not an almost invisible update. Hmmm....

Comment: Removing the layers from last to first significantly helps, but it still flickers.